# Django, how to remove the blank choice from the choicefield in modelform?

Tags: django, forms

I created a model with a foreign key in it:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library, null=False, blank=False)
    ...
```

and then I created a form with a ModelForm to display to the users:

```
class BookSubmitForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

and when I display the page with the form I get the Library choices but also the blank (--------) choice that comes by default.

I thought by having null=False and blank=False in the model that would get rid of that blank choice in the ModelForm but no. What can I do to only have actual choices in the list and not that one?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

See [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). You have to set empty_label to None. So your code will be something like:

```
class BookSubmitForm(ModelForm):
    library = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Library.objects, empty_label=None)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

EDIT:changed the field name to lower case

Comment: It sort of works but I still see the original ChoiceField in the form with the blank choice alongside the new one with the same label and same choices but without the blank choice. It looks this method is not overriding the form but expanding it with the same field.

Comment: Ok my bad, it was a typo, I used an uppercase first letter like in your example "Library". When switching to a lowercase "library" it actually overrides the field. Thanks!

Comment: Great! You can also simply `self.fields['library'].empty_label = None` if you're not going to change the queryset.

Answer (score 15):

`self.fields['xxx'].empty_label = None` would not work If you field type is `TypedChoiceField` which do not have `empty_label` property.
What should we do is to remove first choice:

```
class BookSubmitForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BookSubmitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for field_name in self.fields:
            field = self.fields.get(field_name)
            if field and isinstance(field , forms.TypedChoiceField):
                field.choices = field.choices[1:]
```

Comment: Only use this if you are not able to set a default value for the field in your model, which is a cleaner alternative (see Daniel Sokolowski's answer).

Answer (score 12):

If you specify `blank=False` and `default=<VALUE>` on the model field definition then Django will not render the blank choice by default; do note that the default value can be an invalid choice and set to `''` or any `invalid choice` for example.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library, null=False, blank=False, default='')
    ...
```

Comment: Changing the model just to fit the form doesn't seem right. This should only be done if it makes sense for your model to behave this way.

Answer (score 12):

If you use ModelForm then you don't have to specify queryset, required, label, etc. But for the upvoted answer you have to do it again.

Actually you can do this to avoid re-specifying everything

```
class BookSubmitForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BookSubmitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['library'].empty_label = None

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

Comment: Somehow this doesnt work for me. I still see "---------" as one of the options if set empty_label = None as above. Is this still valid for Django 1.10?

Comment: Actually, I figured it was a TypedChoiceField and hence @Mithril's answer below worked.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to your list of choices (assuming you've made this a CharField) and provide the following code for `None`:

Also, remember that this is an example, not pertaining to the code in question. It is simply meant to help anyone struggling with a default option.

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (None, 'Sex:'),
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
    ('G', 'Gay'),
    ('L', 'Lesbian'),
    ('B', 'Bi'),
    ('O', 'Other')
)
Choose_gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
```

By specifying `None`, you are telling the choice field to default to a certain string. If you want to default to nothing, simply put `''` empty brackets.

Comment: With `(None, ''),`, an selectable box (albeit without `---------`) is still shown.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution works for choice [fields which handle relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships), but it won't work for model fields that have the [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#choices) field set.

For anyone stumbling upon this question while trying to hide the empty choice field when [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#choices) is set, I got it working by providing my own [custom CSS to my model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/media/).

I don't know that hiding the empty choice field makes a lot of sense when using the default [Select](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select) widget, but it does for the [RadioSelect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect) widget.

**Make sure to configure your [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/) setting** and then run `python manage.py collectstatic`

```css
/* STATICFILES_DIRS/css/my_customizations.css */
#id_field_name :has(input[value='']) {
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {"field_name": forms.RadioSelect()}
        # if you're using Django 3.x, you need set the class for inline
        # widgets = {"field_name": forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"class": "inline li"})}

    class Media:
        css = {"all": ("css/my_customizations.css",)}
```

This let me have the option be null initially in the database, but ensure that writers select one of the two fields, and not change it from a valid value to the unset one.

Though, as of January 2023, `:has` is not yet supported by Firefox, but will hopefully be supported [sometime this year](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418039#c61).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).