# Django form selection box 'jammed' as active so cant make selections

Tags: django, forms, dropdown

USERS can Upvote or Downvote Posts/Projects posted by Other Users:
[screenshot of 'jammed' active dropdown selection box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwgj8.jpg)

**THIS CODE DIRECTLY BELOW is the models.py that contains the Project class (model) with the vote_total and vote_ratio fields.
It also contains the Review class (model) which is the basis for the ReviewForm in forms.py (code included later)**

```
class Project(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
featured_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default="default.jpg")
demo_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
source_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
vote_total = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
vote_ratio = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    # ordering = ['-created']
    ordering = ['-vote_ratio', 'vote_total', 'title']
```

**AND here is the Review class (model)**

```
class Review(models.Model):
VOTE_TYPE = (
    ('up', 'Up Vote'),
    ('down', 'Down Vote'),
)
owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
value = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=VOTE_TYPE)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

class Meta:
    unique_together = [['owner', 'project']]

def __str__(self):
    return self.value
```

**Here is the ReviewForm from the forms.py**

```
class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Review
    fields = ['value', 'body']

    labels = {
        'value': 'Place your vote',
        'body': 'Add a comment with your vote'
    }
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ReviewForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for name, field in self.fields.items():
        field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})
```

**Here is the html template where the form is located**

```
<div class="comments">
        <h3 class="singleProject__subtitle">Comments</h3>
        <h5 class="project--rating">
          {{project.vote_ratio}}% Postitive ({{project.vote_total}} Vote{{project.vote_total|pluralize:"s"}})
        </h5>
        
        {% if request.user.profile.id in project.reviewers %}
            <p>You have already submitted a comment!</p>
        {% elif request.user.profile == project.owner %}
            <p>You can't comment your own work!</p>
        {% elif request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <form class="form" action="{% url 'project' project.id %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% for field in form %}
          <div class="form__field">
            <label for="formInput#textarea">{{field.label}} </label>
            {{field}}
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
          <input class="btn btn--sub btn--lg" type="submit" value="Add Review" />
        </form>
        {% else %}
          <a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Please login to leave a comment</a>
        {% endif %}
```

**It was working okay when first implemented and has somehow developed this issue**
This is running in venv with Python 3.9.6

**Thank you for considering this question !**

ADDED - rendered html
[rendered html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXDz7.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by jammed as active? I do not see a problem in your screenshot. Are you unsure about the default value `--------`? If so, remove the empty_label: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8798824/4151233

Comment: It has the 'blue' highlight around the edge (as opposed to the green highlight of other 'fields')  .......the actual problem is that when clicked on it will open and immediately close before the User can make a selection.

Comment: Could be a browser issue autoselecting the field? Have you checked with different browsers?

Comment: I'll give that a try - thank you

Comment: So its a problem on Chrome and Edge.  When i tried firefox, it was highlighted blue and looked like it would have the same 'rapid close' problem, but with firefox the selection opened and remained open until the user made a selection.

Comment: Setting the default value to one of the choices didnt solve the issue for chrome and Edge.

Comment: Share the rendered HTML in your question.

Comment: Thank you Marco - image of rendered html added